# How to make Material UI Desktop Date Picker lose focus on blur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I hope you are doing well! I am facing a bit of a problem and I am unable to find a fix for it.

In my website I have 4 DesktopDatePickers (we are using @mui/x-date-picker) and we want to make the Date Picker appear when we click anywhere on the Textfield (not just the calendar icon). So we have the following code:

```
   <Grid item xs={8} md={5} lg={2}>
                      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                        <DesktopDatePicker
                          label="Creation Date From"
                          inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                          value={dateFrom}
                          onChange={(newValue) => {
                            setDateFrom(newValue);
                            setCreationDateFromOpen(false);
                          }}
                          clearable={true}
                          onClose={() => setCreationDateFromOpen(false)}
                          open={creationDateFromOpen}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              onClick={() => {
                                setCreationDateFromOpen((open) => !open);
                              }}
                              onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                              }}
                              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                                if (e.code !== "Backspace") {
                                  e.preventDefault();
                                }
                              }}
                              onChange={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                              }}
                              fullWidth
                              id="creationDateFrom"
                              size="small"
                              error={false}
                            />
                          )}
                        />
                      </LocalizationProvider>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={8} md={5} lg={2}>
                      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                        <DesktopDatePicker
                          label="Creation Date To"
                          inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                          value={dateTo}
                          onChange={(newValue) => {
                            setDateTo(newValue);
                            setCreationdateToOpen(false);
                          }}
                          clearable={true}
                          open={creationDateToOpen}
                          onClose={() => setCreationdateToOpen(false)}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              onClick={() => {
                                setCreationdateToOpen((open) => !open);
                              }}
                              onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                              }}
                              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                                if (e.code !== "Backspace") {
                                  e.preventDefault();
                                }
                              }}
                              onChange={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                              }}
                              fullWidth
                              size="small"
                              error={false}
                            />
                          )}
                        />
                      </LocalizationProvider>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={8} md={5} lg={2}>
                      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                        <DesktopDatePicker
                          label="Delivery Date From"
                          inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                          value={requestDateFrom}
                          onChange={(newValue) => {
                            setRequestDateFrom(newValue);
                            setModificationDateFromOpen(false);
                          }}
                          clearable={true}
                          open={modificationDateFromOpen}
                          onClose={() => setModificationDateFromOpen(false)}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                              }}
                              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                                if (e.code !== "Backspace") {
                                  e.preventDefault();
                                }
                              }}
                              onChange={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                              }}
                              onClick={() => {
                                setModificationDateFromOpen((open) => !open);
                              }}
                              fullWidth
                              size="small"
                              error={false}
                            />
                          )}
                        />
                      </LocalizationProvider>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={8} md={5} lg={2}>
                      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                        <DesktopDatePicker
                          label="Delivery Date To"
                          inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                          value={requestDateTo}
                          onChange={(newValue) => {
                            setRequestDateTo(newValue);
                            setModificationDateToOpen(false);
                          }}
                          clearable={true}
                          open={modificationDateToOpen}
                          onClose={() => setModificationDateToOpen(false)}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                              }}
                              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                                if (e.code !== "Backspace") {
                                  e.preventDefault();
                                }
                              }}
                              onChange={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                              }}
                              onClick={() => {
                                setModificationDateToOpen((open) => !open);
                              }}
                              fullWidth
                              size="small"
                              error={false}
                            />
                          )}
                        />
                      </LocalizationProvider>
                    </Grid>
```

However, We are running through a problem. If a user clicks on one textfield it Focuses then loses focus but displays the Date Picker, but directly after it, they click anywhere and the Date Picker disappears (which is supposed to happen) but the field regains Focus so it looks like the field is awaiting input. So clicking on any other field while the Date Picker is open causes that field to Focus then lose focus and the Browser focuses the Date Field again.

I tried using `onFocus={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}` in the renderInput TextField but the field still got focused. Using `ref.current.blur()` gives an error that `blur()` does not exist.

How can I make the Field not Focus when closing the DatePicker?